# Modify bootstrap carousel to display multiple slides simultaneously

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm wanting to modify bootstrap 3's carousel to display several slides at once. I know that I could put multiple thumbnails in a single slide (div .item) but the problem with that is that the carousel will slide past them all simultaneously moving on to the next group whereas **I'm wanting to step through them one by one**.

I've found an example of exactly what I want here: http://www.bootply.com/117282 The only problem with this is that I need 5 or 6 slides visible as oppose to 4. I've spent several hours attempting to modify this to work as desired but I clearly don't have a sufficient understanding of how it works.

My jquery/javascript understanding is pretty elementary but my CSS is pretty decent. Could someone show me how to modify this to display 5/6 slides simultaneously? I really appreciate the help.

Thanks,
Sharma

Comment: You should show an example of what you have tried, so people can help you better with what you need to change.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you just want to overide this fiddle so :

**1** :
In JS : change    `for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {`   by  `for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {`

**2** : 
In HTML : change `col-lg-3` (so 4 items) by `col-lg-2` (so 6 items)

**bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/123662

Comment: Wow that's fantastic, thank you. I've now set the for loop to `for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {` as well as setting the span-lg-2 to a width of 20% which seems to effectively give me five columns. http://www.bootply.com/123662



For anyone els wanting to implement you also need to change the css to move the slider by the corect amount with `.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -20%; }` and `.carousel-inner .next { left:  20%; }`

Comment: @user3446373 You can thank the author of the fiddle, not me... But please, if your issue is solved, can you accept the answer to close the post ? (at left of answer, bottom of arrows)

Comment: This is wonderful. how can I make the left arrow move one as well ?

Comment: If someone is looking for the answer, how to move to the left 1 at a time as well, here is the answer:
.carousel-inner .active.right { left: 16.6% ; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left:  -16.6% ; }

Comment: @YenneInfo can this be updated for Bootstrap 3.3.5? It doesn't seem to work here: http://www.bootply.com/yNdE51hs8o

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap 5

This is an 2022 update. Bootstrap has changed a lot since 3, even 4. The codes below are easy to customize and adapt to your needs without disrupting entering in conflict with any custom css you might have.

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/hellomev/pen/LYORMQW) and new BS5 docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/)

**Prerequisites**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**JS**

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

        items.forEach((el) => {
            const minPerSlide = 4
            let next = el.nextElementSibling
            for (var i=1; i<minPerSlide; i++) {
                if (!next) {
            // wrap carousel by using first child
            next = items[0]
        }
        let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
        el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
        next = next.nextElementSibling
    }
})
```