# Bootstrap 3 carousel with multiple items

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have implemented a **multiple item carousel** using **Bootstrap3** <del>as [shown in this demo](http://www.bootply.com/132400)</del>. It displays 4 items at a time.

How can I change that? I'd like to show 5 or 6 items at a time.

Comment: Have a look here, may help you aswell.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558936/modify-bootstrap-carousel-to-display-multiple-slides-simultaneously

Comment: @akiaWT updated my answer to fix animation bug...please accept if it solves the issue for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple changes are needed:

In JS change `i<2` to `i<3` (will display 5 across) or `i<4` (will display 6 across)

In HTML change your `<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">` to something that will accomodate more cells, for example `<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">`.  (This is optional, but 6 across in a col-md-6 looks pretty tight in my opinion)

Change `col-md-3` to `col-md-2`.  Note that this will change the carousel only on medium and large resolution screens.  To adjust the width on `sm` and `xs` you would need to adjust the `col` sizes for `col-sm` and `col-xs`

Then in your CSS change to accodomate for 6 across in the animation by changing 25% (`100%/4`) to 16.7% (`100%/6`).  If you want 5 across, you would change this to 20%.

```
@media (min-width: 992px ) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -16.7%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  16.7%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -16.7%; }  
}
```

#### [Updated Bootply with 6 across](http://www.bootply.com/IQ5RPxXjZ9)

Comment: It worked. Is there a way to add dynamic images to the carousel, instead of static images. Etc. array of 10 images retrieved from a database insert and display in a carousel.

Comment: Sure there is a way, but that's a separate question/issue.  You could use a `foreach` loop to generate your html and then dynamically generate your CSS using jQuery based on the number of elements on the page.  It's not a simple thing but it's manageable if necessary.

Comment: I'm having this **multiple item slider** and a **normal(1 item) slider** inside a single page. But because of the media query you mentioned above, the normal slider doesn't work properly.Anything about that??

Comment: Bit late, but just to answer the last comment/question for future reference. Simply add a unique id (id="my-unique-carousel-id") to the carousel that contains multiple items and reference this in your media queries/CSS. So instead of ".carousel-inner .active.left { left: -16.7%; }" it would say "#my-unique-carousel-id .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -16.7%; }"

Answer (score 0):

Simply by changing the limit on the for call

```
for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
 }
```

Now has six.

Of course you'll want to keep the columns in order by changing `col-md-3` to `col-md-2`