# Bootstrap thumbnail scroller

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want something like this bootstrap thumbnail scroller, that I can scroll one by one on click.

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: false
    })
});
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340705/bootstrap-3-carousel-with-multiple-items/25340820#25340820

Comment: Starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850099/carousel-with-thumbnails-in-bootstrap-3-0

Comment: dan, i need that for bootstrap 2