# Bootstrap Carousel Sliding 1 Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so after some hard work i managed to make my carousel work on my webpage and everything works fine but i would like the carousel to slide just one image to the left or right not all of them. Is this possible to make?

HTML:

```
  <html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's Javascript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Header + Navigation Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Header_CSS.css"/>
</head>

<!-- Body -->
<body>

<div id="back_carousel"><p></p></div>

<div class="<a href="#" id="_GPLITA_0" in_rurl="http://i.display-trk.com/click?v=Tkw6NTg5ODE6MTE1MDpjb250YWluZXI6ZDQ1ODdjOTgxNzBhMWFhZjBkYTNkYjZiMGY0YzI0MTQ6ei0xNzUwLTQ1ODUxNjp3d3cuZHJlYW1pbmNvZGUubmV0OjE4MTU3MjowOjBkNjkzMDQ3YWFjZDRlMTViZTFhMGIxYmY3MTg4YmI2OjE&subid=g-458516-1f06d94172a34404b791c3395bb688bc-&data_tagname=PRE" title="Click to Continue > by NextCoup" style="border: none !important; display: inline-block !important; text-indent: 0px !important; float: none !important; font-weight: bold !important; height: auto !important; margin: 0px !important; min-height: 0px !important; min-width: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; text-transform: uppercase !important; text-decoration: underline !important; vertical-align: baseline !important; width: auto !important; background: transparent !important;">container<img src="http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/it/img/arrow-10x10.png" style="border: none !important; display: inline-block !important; text-indent: 0px !important; float: none !important; font-weight: bold !important; height: 10px !important; margin: 0px 0px 0px 3px !important; min-height: 0px !important; min-width: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; text-transform: uppercase !important; text-decoration: underline !important; vertical-align: super !important; width: 10px !important; background: transparent !important;"></a>-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">

    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="Galaxy.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Samsung S5</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            </div>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="lg g2.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>LG G3</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            </div>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="Windows9.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            </div>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="htc.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            </div>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="beats.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 
            <div class="item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="Galaxy.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            </div>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            </div>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            </div>                      
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            </div>                       
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide2 -->  
        </div>

        <div class="control-box">                            
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><h2><</h2></a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><h2>></h2></a>
        </div><!-- /.control-box -->   

    </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

</div><!-- /.span12 -->          
</div><!-- /.row --> 
</div><!-- /.container -->                            
</body>
</html>
<!-- Nav end -->
```

CSS:

```
![#myCarousel{
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#C2C2C2;
    z-index:1;
}
#back_carousel{
    position:relative;
    top:-15spx;
    width: 2000px;
    height:278px;
    background-color:#C2C2C2;
}
/* Global */

img { max-width:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}


a {
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease;
    transition: all 150ms ease; 
    }
    .thumbnail a:hover {
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.<a href="#" id="_GPLITA_1" in_rurl="http://i.display-trk.com/click?v=Tkw6NTg5ODE6MTE1MDptaWNyb3NvZnQ6ODNlN2FlNjc2ZTU2YWRjZGE1MGNmOTBhZTBkYmJmZDc6ei0xNzUwLTQ1ODUxNjp3d3cuZHJlYW1pbmNvZGUubmV0OjE4MTU3MjowOmE0YTNiZjljMDAzMjQyZjE5YTJjMmMzMzhhMjJjOWQ0OjE&subid=g-458516-1f06d94172a34404b791c3395bb688bc-&data_tagname=PRE" title="Click to Continue > by NextCoup" style="border: none !important; display: inline-block !important; text-indent: 0px !important; float: none !important; font-weight: bold !important; height: auto !important; margin: 0px !important; min-height: 0px !important; min-width: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; text-transform: uppercase !important; text-decoration: underline !important; vertical-align: baseline !important; width: auto !important; background: transparent !important;">Microsoft<img src="http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/it/img/arrow-10x10.png" style="border: none !important; display: inline-block !important; text-indent: 0px !important; float: none !important; font-weight: bold !important; height: 10px !important; margin: 0px 0px 0px 3px !important; min-height: 0px !important; min-width: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; text-transform: uppercase !important; text-decoration: underline !important; vertical-align: super !important; width: 10px !important; background: transparent !important;"></a>.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /* IE 8 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE7 */
        opacity: 0.65;
        text-decoration: none;
    }   
/* Container */
.container-fluid {
    width:1000px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    }

/* Thumbnail Box */

.caption h4 {
    position:absolute;
    top:230px;
    color:white;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight:400;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
font-family: Jubilat,Georgia,serif;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-indent: 15px;
    }
    .caption p {
        font-size: 0.75rem;
        color: green;
        text-indent: 15px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        }

/* Carousel Control */
.control-box {
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: right;
    width:  100%;
    }
    .carousel-control {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:10;
        background:transparent;
        border: 0px;
        border-radius:0px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Sans serif;
        font-size: 34px;
        font-weight: 200;
        line-height: 18px;
        opacity: 0.5;
        padding: 4px 10px 0px;
        height: 274px;
        width: 15px;
        text-decoration:none;
        }

/* Mobile Only */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .page-header, .control-box {
    text-align: center;
    } 
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
    .caption {
    word-break: break-all;
    }
}

/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.2.0 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

/*! normalize.css v3.0.1 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  right:5px;
  width: 1910px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
       -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
          transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img { 
  line-height: 1;
}
.carousel-inner > .active,
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .6;
}

.carousel-control.left {
    left: -15;
    right:<a href="#" id="_GPLITA_2" in_rurl="http://i.display-trk.com/click?v=Tkw6NDk3MzU6MTMwNDphdXRvczpmMTUxOWRiNmJjZDE5OTcwMWJjNzdmMDMwZjUyODU0Nzp6LTE3NTAtNDU4NTE2Ond3dy5kcmVhbWluY29kZS5uZXQ6MjA4MTAzOmVkMDVkZjNlZDhlNGU4Zjc0ZWMwMWNlNjIyNmQzMjFhOjVlMGQxYzU0ODlkYzQ0Zjc4YWUyNDFmMmJjNjY0NzdlOjE&subid=g-458516-1f06d94172a34404b791c3395bb688bc-&data_tagname=PRE" title="Click to Continue > by NextCoup" style="border: none !important; display: inline-block !important; text-indent: 0px !important; float: none !important; font-weight: bold !important; height: auto !important; margin: 0px !important; min-height: 0px !important; min-width: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; text-transform: uppercase !important; text-decoration: underline !important; vertical-align: baseline !important; width: auto !important; background: transparent !important;">auto<img src="http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/it/img/arrow-10x10.png" style="border: none !important; display: inline-block !important; text-indent: 0px !important; float: none !important; font-weight: bold !important; height: 10px !important; margin: 0px 0px 0px 3px !important; min-height: 0px !important; min-width: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; text-transform: uppercase !important; text-decoration: underline !important; vertical-align: super !important; width: 10px !important; background: transparent !important;"></a>;
    max-width:100px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001)));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.carousel-control.right {
    max-width:100px;
  right: -15;
  left: <a href="#" id="_GPLITA_3" in_rurl="http://i.display-trk.com/click?v=Tkw6NDk3MzU6MTMwNDphdXRvczpkN2RkNzZhOWIwOWY3MWM5YTRkMWMxZTlkYmNkNDczZDp6LTE3NTAtNDU4NTE2Ond3dy5kcmVhbWluY29kZS5uZXQ6OTcwNTM6MWUwNzZkMTdiYmE2MWQxOTU2YTk2OGVhNTQxNjY0ZjA6M2IzMWU1MjEwZWIxNDZiYWJlY2E1NmU3OWUyZDRhY2Q6MQ&subid=g-458516-1f06d94172a34404b791c3395bb688bc-&data_tagname=PRE" title="Click to Continue > by NextCoup" style="border: none !important; display: inline-block !important; text-indent: 0px !important; float: none !important; font-weight: bold !important; height: auto !important; margin: 0px !important; min-height: 0px !important; min-width: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; text-transform: uppercase !important; text-decoration: underline !important; vertical-align: baseline !important; width: auto !important; background: transparent !important;">auto<img src="http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/it/img/arrow-10x10.png" style="border: none !important; display: inline-block !important; text-indent: 0px !important; float: none !important; font-weight: bold !important; height: 10px !important; margin: 0px 0px 0px 3px !important; min-height: 0px !important; min-width: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; text-transform: uppercase !important; text-decoration: underline !important; vertical-align: super !important; width: 10px !important; background: transparent !important;"></a>;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  left: 6px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  font-family: serif;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
  content: '\2039';
}
.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
  content: '\203a';
}
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -30%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000 \9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
.carousel-caption .btn {
  text-shadow: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
  .carousel-control .icon-prev,
  .carousel-control .icon-next {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
  .carousel-control .icon-prev {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
  .carousel-control .icon-next {
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    right: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 20px;
  }][1]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify bootstrap carousel to display multiple slides simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558936/modify-bootstrap-carousel-to-display-multiple-slides-simultaneously)

Comment: You can use the  algorythm of duplicate and hack it to TB2

Comment: your code is an absolute mess, starting from the first div with that strange code which is repeated in the CSS as well. Anyways, I tried cleaning up your mess and it works fine, as long as you use only 1 image per .item class, as supposed. If you add 5 images, it will show 5.

Comment: thank you very much for cleaning up my code (not very good at keeping code clean). But can you explain how to show 5 images on page but only shift one to the left or right or did you already do that? anyway thank you very much.

Comment: something like this : [link](http://www.bootply.com/123662)