# Infinite carousel with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an carousel and i'm using Twitter Bootstrap.

I have to fit 5 items in it. I'll make a simple example:

```
<div id="carolsel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
               <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <p>Content</p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <p>Content</p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <p>Content</p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <p>Content</p>
               </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
               <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <p>Content</p>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

It shows 4 items and then shows one item alone.
There's a way to make an infinite carousel so the first content appears right after the last?

The `item` divs are created dynamically by and foreach, the contents comes from an MYSQL database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify bootstrap carousel to display multiple slides simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558936/modify-bootstrap-carousel-to-display-multiple-slides-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior for Bootstrap 3 carousel is to cycle through the items, in an infinite manner. See the first carousel example from the Bootstrap 3 documentation: [Bootstrap 3 documentation - see carousel section](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

From the documentation on carousel, in the Options section, the setting that controls the cycle behavior is named wrap and the default value is set to **true** so that it cycles continuously.

In the example HTML that follows (from documentation), please note that each content (image, etc.) will go in its own div container:

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing this, I have to put each content in an `item` div?

Comment: Yes, and edited the original answer to reflect an HTML example illustrating this.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. But i want to show 4 contents, then after show 1 last content and the first 3 others from the 4 initials.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're trying to do. Show 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, then 1+2+3 in the same container?

Comment: Yep. 1 2 3 4 - slide - 5 1 2 3 - slide - 4 5 1 2 - slide - 3 4 5 1 and goes on and on.