# How to show images which loop infinitely in carousel (images getting from database)

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have the following codes which pull images from a database and show in Bootstrap's - carousel.

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <?php
 $carouselImageSql = "SELECT * FROM indexPageElements WHERE carouseImage = '1'";
 $carouselImageResult = mysqli_query($conn, $carouselImageSql);

 $i = 0;
 while($carouselImageRow = mysqli_fetch_array($carouselImageResult)){
  $imageLocation = $carouselImageRow['carouseImageLocation'];
  
  echo '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="" ></li>';
 ?>
 </ol>
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 <?php
  if($i == 0){
   echo '<div class="carousel-item active">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/'.$imageLocation.'" alt="First slide">
   </div>';
  }else{
   echo '<div class="carousel-item">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/'.$imageLocation.'" alt="First slide">
   </div>';
  }
  
  $i += 1;
 }
 ?>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**My Issue**

My problem here is, once all the images pulled out from database, carousel stop showing those pictures again. Does anyone knows how to grab the picture from database and show it in carousel but at the same time loops infinitely?

**Edit 1**

I did the following to loop it for 10 times. But still it is only for 10 times

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <?php
 $carouselImageSql = "SELECT * FROM indexPageElements WHERE carouseImage = '1'";
 $carouselImageResult = mysqli_query($conn, $carouselImageSql);
 $carouselImageCount = mysqli_num_rows($carouselImageResult);
  
 $imageLocation = array();
 
 while($carouselImageRow = mysqli_fetch_array($carouselImageResult)){
  $imageLocation[] = $carouselImageRow['carouseImageLocation'];
  echo '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="" ></li>';
 }

 ?>
 </ol>
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 <?php
  $i = 0;
  for($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++){
   foreach($imageLocation as $loc){
    if($i == 0){
     echo '<div class="carousel-item active">
       <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/'.$loc.'" alt="First slide">
     </div>';
    }else{
     echo '<div class="carousel-item">
       <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/'.$loc.'" alt="First slide">
     </div>';
    }
    $i += 1;
   }
  }
 ?>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#options --- Get all your pictures from the database before using them.  Have them in a single array.  Use them in your carousel by looping through that array, apply the option you need to get it to cycle continuously.

Comment: This is what you are looking for. https://infinite-scroll.com/

Comment: How is that what he is looking for? It's a bootstrap carousel, and he needs it to loop...

Comment: @Dammeul I did some try with arrays. Please see my Edit 1. But it is still for 10 times only. I didn't get your point of making it infinite loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite carousel with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279473/infinite-carousel-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I mean is to turn on the `wrap` option, as below:

```
$("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel({ wrap: true });
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#options:

`Wrap` is whether the carousel should cycle continuously or have hard stops.

you will need JQuery and Bootstrap JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to activate your carousel with this short javascript.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Activate Carousel
    $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel();
});
</script>
```